# How to make a 3D-Plot from 2D-interpolated data

Tags: plotting, interpolation

I have data of the form `{x,y}` for different concentrations. Therefore I added the concentration as `z`, resulting now in `{x,y,z}`.

Example data (for concentrations A:1%, B:2%, C:4%):

```
dataA = {{1, 20, 1}, {2, 19, 1}, {3, 18, 1}, {4, 17, 1}, {5, 16, 1}};

dataB = {{1, 20, 2}, {2, 19.5, 2}, {3, 19, 2}, {4, 19.5, 2}, {5, 16, 2}};

dataC = {{1, 20, 4}, {2, 21, 4}, {3, 20.5, 4}, {4, 19.5, 4}, {5, 16, 4}};
```

Now I want to make a 3D surface plot from these traces (by 2D-interpolation). How to do that?

**Edit:** the real data here:
[dropboxlink](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1086xkjq5pj38a0/Sample%20data%20for%203D%20plot.xlsx)

Comment: May be `ListSurfacePlot3D`? (You need at least 10 points)

Comment: Thank you, ListSurfacePlot3D seem not to work on my real data. I provided them by editing the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
r = RotateRight /@ Join[dataA, dataB, dataC];
f = Interpolation[{#[[1 ;; 2]], #[[3]]} & /@ r]; 
Show[{Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], Point@r}, Axes -> True], 
      Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 1.`, 4.`}, {y, 1.`, 5.`}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

Here you have your DropBox Data

```
r0 = Import["c:\\test.xlsx", "Data"]; 
ListPlot3D[ RotateRight /@ Flatten[r0, 1], Mesh -> False,  ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: `ListPlot3D` should suffice, it does interpolation automatically.

Comment: @Szabolcs Perhaps, yes. But in cases like this one I always find myself tweaking the options of `ListPlot3D[]` to get a smooth enough surface.

Comment: Thank you, but all answers seem not to work on my real data. I provided them by editing the question.

Comment: @Shukoff See edit, please

Comment: @belisarius: Thank you very much!